# cannot map entities using entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have in database two tables: product, supplier
I want the entity framework to define the supplier of each product
I am getting data successfully for two tables but the supplier in the product table is null.
Also, the products collection in the supplier table is null.
this is my product class:

```
public class Product 
{       
   public int  id { get; set; }           
   [Column("Productname", TypeName = "ntext")]
   public string Name { get; set; }           
   public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
   public bool isDiscounted { get; set; }
   public int quantity { get; set; }            
   public int SupplierId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("SupplierId")]
   public  Supplier supplier { get; set; }            
}
```

this is the class of supplier:

```
public class Supplier
{           
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   public string ContactName { get; set; }
   public string  ContactTitle { get; set; }
   public string city { get; set; }
   public string country { get; set; }
   public string phone { get; set; }
   public string Fax { get; set; }
   public List<Product> Products { get; set; }    
 }
```

context class:

```
 public class DbConext : DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public DbConext(DbContextOptions<DbConext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Product");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().ToTable("Supplier");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey("id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().HasKey("Id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOne(p => p.supplier).WithMany(s => s.Products).HasForeignKey(p => p.SupplierId);                  
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) article might help.

You should use `.Include()` to load any related properties.

Comment: where to add **Incclode()** ? I am very new to entity framework @John Doe

Comment: ```context.Products.Include(p => p.Supplier)```, where ```context``` is an instance of your DBContext class. After that you can filter your collection however you like.

Answer (score 0):

minimum you need is to initialize the list

```
public  class Supplier
{
    
   public  int Id { get; set; }
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   public string ContactName { get; set; }
   public string  ContactTitle { get; set; }
   public string city { get; set; }
   public string country { get; set; }
   public string phone { get; set; }
   public string Fax { get; set; }
   public  List<Product> Products { get; set; }

   public Supplier() {
      this.Products = new List<Product>();
   }
}
```